# OPTIONAL MATCH and WHERE do not work properly together

Tags: neo4j, cypher

take the following query:

```
MATCH (p: Post)-[r]->(reply: Post) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (profile:Profile)-[r2:Likes]->(reply) 
WHERE p.key = $postKey
RETURN reply, collect(profile.key)
```

The intent is to return all the replies to a given post and tell you anyone who like them if anyone has liked them.  The second match is optional because you should still return all replies that are not liked.  Instead what comes back is all replies period.  The following query does work:

```
MATCH (p: Post {key:$postKey})-[r]->(reply: Post) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (profile:Profile)-[r2:Likes]->(reply)  
RETURN reply, collect(profile.key)
```

Now I understand this to an extent in that Cypher queries are sequentially executed not processed then executed as a whole.  So in the second example it gets only the replies to the given post then gets the likes then returns whereas in the first example it first gets all replies then gets all likes then should filter them.  My questions are as follows:

1. Is why doesn't it filter them?  I'm assuming that the optional match is causing the Post to no longer be in the dataset thus the filter is ignored.
2. Is there a way to use where and not have this happen?
3. Lastly given that this really drives home the sequential nature should you use where for key lookup or should it be avoided for performance reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of this misunderstanding is that WHERE is not a standalone clause, it modifies the previous MATCH, OPTIONAL MATCH, or WITH clause.

It will help to read these as a pair...

`MATCH ... WHERE ...`

`WITH ... WHERE ...`

`OPTIONAL MATCH ... WHERE ...`

The behavior of OPTIONAL MATCH is that no results will be filtered out. Instead, if the OPTIONAL MATCH fails (and that includes the result of its paired WHERE clause) newly introduced variables in the OPTIONAL MATCH pattern come back as null.

So with that info, you can see that your WHERE clause is actually in the wrong place. It's associated with the OPTIONAL MATCH when it should instead follow the MATCH, constraining those results (and allowing an index lookup if you have an index on :Post(key)).

One other means you could use to fix (less correct in this particular case, but useful in other cases) is to follow the OPTIONAL MATCH with a `WITH ... WHERE ...`, which will allow the WHERE clause to filter out results.

More info on this in [one of our Neo4j knowledge base articles](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/why-where-clause-does-not-filter/).

Comment: So that addresses 1 that they are sequential, and 2 that the with can solve this, but what about 3.  Is there a memory performance hit to using where vs directly filtering in the match clause?

Comment: It's not necessarily sequential. At least, MATCHes aren't necessarily sequential, the planner has room to figure out how to execute a query, and that can include figuring out its own order of execution. As for performance hits, it matters. When your WHERE was associated with the OPTIONAL MATCH, it wasn't being considered by your first MATCH, and so an index lookup wasn't possible, changing the plan and query execution, giving you bad results and bad performance. If the filtering is relevant to the match, and might influence index lookup, pair it with the the right clause.

Comment: But as for whether to define a property value inline in the pattern vs in the associated WHERE clause, there is no difference, it's syntactical sugar, and should evaluate to the same query plan (you can check with EXPLAIN or PROFILE).